# ValueError: can only convert an array of size 1 to a Python scalar : apply lambda to function

Tags: python, pandas, function, lambda

I have two data frames that share the two common columns "a" and "b". I would like to create a function that sums up the values of "amount" by class in df1, and add this to df2 as "sum" column.

Here's df1 and df2.

```
df1
    a         b   class amount
0   orange  ichi    1   10
1   apple   ni      2   20
2   peach   san     3   40
3   banana  shi     2   15
4   lemon   go      1   30
```

```
df2
 a          b     
0   apple   ni     
1   orange  ichi   
2   lemon   go     
3   peach   san    
4   banana  shi    
5   apple   ni   
6   lemon   go
```

And I would like to add "sum" column in df2 like this.

```
df2
 a          b      sum
0   apple   ni     35
1   orange  ichi   40
2   lemon   go     40
3   peach   san    30
4   banana  shi    35
5   apple   ni     35
6   lemon   go     40
```

I created this function that returns the total number of "amount" by group.

```
#function
def num_count(a,b):
    
    df1["sum"] = df1.groupby(['class'])['amount'].transform('sum')
    amount_total = df1["sum"][(df1["a"] == str(a)) & (df1["b"] == str(b))]
    return amount_total.item()
```

I'm trying to apply this function to df2, but I got an error as below.
Does anyone know how to fix this error?

```
df2['sum'] = df2.apply(lambda x: num_count(x['a'], x['b']), axis=1)

>>> ValueError: can only convert an array of size 1 to a Python scalar
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to solve via merge:

1. Evaluate the sum 1st from the first dataframe via `groupby/transform`. Transform allows you to retain the original structure of the dataframe.
2. Assign the result back to the 1st dataframe using `assign` method.
3. Drop the non-required column from the 1st dataframe.
4. Finally do the left merge

```
df2 = (
    df2.merge(
        df1.assign(
            sum=df1.groupby(['class'])['amount']
            .transform('sum'))
        .drop(['class', 'amount'], 1
              ),
        how='left',
        on=['a', 'b'])
)
```

Output:

```
        a     b  sum
0   apple    ni   35
1  orange  ichi   40
2   lemon    go   40
3   peach   san   40
4  banana   shi   35
5   apple    ni   35
6   lemon    go   40
```